# Using multiple UITableViewCell on a Table

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm trying to use two different type of custom cell on my table. My idea its the following

2 - Sections
1 - Row

```
-- Section 1
 - Row

-- Section 2
 - Row
```

Thats, its! I'm getting this error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource
>   must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 2;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 1;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section;
{
    return 10.; // you can have your own choice, of course
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    headerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    return headerView;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
{
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
            HeaderCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            if (cell == nil) {
                cell = [[HeaderCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
                                         reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            }
            PFFile *eventImage = [self.event objectForKey:@"eventPoster"];
            cell.headerImage.file = eventImage;
            [cell.headerImage loadInBackground];
            NSAttributedString *eventNameAtt;
            eventNameAtt = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self.event[@"eventName"]uppercaseString]]
                                                           attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"ProximaNova-Semibold" size:15],
                                                                        NSStrokeColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor],
                                                                        NSKernAttributeName : @(3.0F)}];
            cell.eventLabel.attributedText = eventNameAtt;
            cell.eventLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            NSAttributedString *eventLocation;
            eventLocation = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self.eventLocation[@"Name"]uppercaseString]]
                                                            attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"ProximaNova-Light" size:11],

                                                                         NSStrokeColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor],

                                                                         NSKernAttributeName : @(3.0F)}];

            cell.eventLabel.attributedText = eventNameAtt;
            cell.eventLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            cell.placeLabel.attributedText = eventLocation;
            cell.placeLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            return cell;
    }
        if (indexPath.section == 1) {
            if (indexPath.row == 0) {
                static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"About";
                AboutCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
                if (cell == nil) {
                    cell = [[AboutCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
                                            reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
                    cell.testLabel.text = @"Test";
                    cell.testLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
                    return cell;
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
            return nil;

    }
```

Comment: Both cell are using the same CellIdentifier, so it would get the same   prototype cell

Comment: @Horst not really, one identifier its "Cell" and the other one its "About"

Comment: What do you mean, "Apperantly I'm getting an empty cell"? What do actually see? where are your cells made (storyboard, xib, code)?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of info.

I'm getting this error: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'

And they are on StoryBoard. Reuse Identifier its stated on storyboard

Comment: oops, sorry, what i saw is there is no return cell in section 1. As AboutCell is valid, it won't goes into the if block. Then return nil

Comment: So, do you still have the same problem?

Comment: Can you answer my first comment please?

Comment: @rdelmar I don't see anything, I get this error: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'
*** First throw call stack:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I'd remove the inner IF blocks because if you've only got one row per section, then the row should **always** be zero.

Secondly, inside your section 1 block, your `return cell;` is inside the inner IF block, therefore it won't be called if a cell is successfully dequeued. Move it outside your `if (cell == nil)` block.

Therefore:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
        HeaderCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[HeaderCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
                                     reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }
        PFFile *eventImage = [self.event objectForKey:@"eventPoster"];
        cell.headerImage.file = eventImage;
        [cell.headerImage loadInBackground];
        NSAttributedString *eventNameAtt;
        eventNameAtt = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self.event[@"eventName"]uppercaseString]]
                                                       attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"ProximaNova-Semibold" size:15],
                                                                    NSStrokeColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor],
                                                                    NSKernAttributeName : @(3.0F)}];
        cell.eventLabel.attributedText = eventNameAtt;
        cell.eventLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        NSAttributedString *eventLocation;
        eventLocation = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self.eventLocation[@"Name"]uppercaseString]]
                                                        attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"ProximaNova-Light" size:11],

                                                                     NSStrokeColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor],

                                                                     NSKernAttributeName : @(3.0F)}];

        cell.eventLabel.attributedText = eventNameAtt;
        cell.eventLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.placeLabel.attributedText = eventLocation;
        cell.placeLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        return cell;
    }
    if (indexPath.section == 1) {

        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"About";
        AboutCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[AboutCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
                                    reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        }

        cell.testLabel.text = @"Test";
        cell.testLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        return cell;
    }
return nil;
}
```

Comment: it returns 2 in numberOfSectionsInTableView.

Comment: @siburb Thank you! 2nd Advice did the trick!

Again, thank you.

Comment: @Horst - Yes, but returns 1 from numberOfRowsInSection

Comment: @outime, if you made your cells in the storyboard, there's  no need to check if the cell is nil, since it never will be.

Comment: This code won't compile. You will get compiler error stating that there is no return statement at the end of the `cellForRow...` method.

Comment: Good point - thanks @maddy. It should never happen (and will crash the app if it is ever reached), but we need that "return nil;".
Have edited answer.

Comment: @rmaddy Thank you, yes thats exactly why I have return nil at the end.